# mysql database dump script adding fuctionality to skip dumped database

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm using the following script to dump my database. it works great. I want  to add functionality that it first checks if a database table is already dumped or not, if a dump exists then it should be skipped and move to the next table.

```
DB_host=127.0.0.1
DB_user=root
DB=mydb
DB_pass=mydbpassword
DIR=/

[ -n "$DIR" ] || DIR=.
test -d $DIR || mkdir -p $DIR

echo "Dumping tables into separate SQL command files for database '$DB' into dir=$DIR"

tbl_count=0

for t in $(mysql -NBA -h $DB_host -u $DB_user -p$DB_pass -D $DB -e 'show tables')
do
    echo "DUMPING TABLE: $t"
    mysqldump -h $DB_host -u $DB_user -p$DB_pass $DB $t  > $DIR/$t.sql
    (( tbl_count++ ))
done

echo "$tbl_count tables dumped from database '$DB' into dir=$DIR"
```

Comment: You seem to know how to check if a directory exists already. Do you need anything else than to check if a file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this block of the code:

```
echo "DUMPING TABLE: $t"
mysqldump -h $DB_host -u $DB_user -p$DB_pass $DB $t  > $DIR/$t.sql
(( tbl_count++ ))
```

To this:

```
echo "DUMPING TABLE: $t"
if [ -e "$DIR/$t.sql" ]; then
  echo "TABLE $DIR/$t.sql exists, skipping..."
else
  mysqldump -h $DB_host -u $DB_user -p$DB_pass $DB $t  > $DIR/$t.sql
fi
(( tbl_count++ ))
```